# Can a card in Trello display a table?

Tags: trello, markdown

The markdown syntax says that you can use regular HTML and specifically mentions `<table>` as being possible. The only restrictions being that you have blank lines before and after the table, and that the `<table>` and `</table>` tags are not indented.

But this doesn't appear to work in Trello.

Is this just not supported, or is there a way to do this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There are two common ways to render tables inside markdown content:

- By embedding HTML using `<table> <tr> <td>` tags
- Using special table syntax, which is not an official part of the [markdown spec](http://spec.commonmark.org/0.25/), but is supported in certain libraries including [Github Flavoured Markdown (GFM)](https://help.github.com/articles/organizing-information-with-tables/)

Unfortunately **the [markdown library used by Trello](https://github.com/evilstreak/markdown-js) doesn't support either of these options - so no tables in Trello for the time being**.

As others have partly mentioned, the imperfect workarounds are:

- Fake tables by using a code block
- Upload/embed an image that displays your table
- Link to a Google Doc/Spreadsheet or some other URL

Answer (score 35):

You can sort of fake it by using three backticks (```) to create a code block like this:

````
```
| Tables        | Are           | Cool  |
| ------------- |:-------------:| -----:|
| col 3 is      | right-aligned | $1600 |
| col 2 is      | centered      |   $12 |
| zebra stripes | are neat      |    $1 |
```
````

which creates this:

```
| Tables        | Are           | Cool  |
| ------------- |:-------------:| -----:|
| col 3 is      | right-aligned | $1600 |
| col 2 is      | centered      |   $12 |
| zebra stripes | are neat      |    $1 |
```

Comment: And you can easily create a great ASCII table [here](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/)

Comment: or at [tablesgenerator.com](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables)

Comment: And https://tableconvert.com/ can convert _from_ HTML tables, something I couldn't find on the others listed in the comments here.

Answer (score 3):

This markdown cheat sheet includes tables: https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet - but it doesn't appear to work in Trello.

Comment: `Tables aren't part of the core Markdown spec, but they are part of GFM and Markdown Here supports them.` which is feature of github. So it won't work in trello.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, download the Trello Table Markdown Chrome extension.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pgifaolbebmlmfafkgngfjchfpcpndig

Or better yet: download the full featured Trello Cards Optimizer version:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/trello-cards-optimizer/ipbjjbpopodbnjbjnneakhcppdocpelg

Both are free.

Comment: The former extension is obsolete now, the developer recommends the latter.

Answer (score 2):

if migrating to a different planning app is an option for you, then have a look at [Favro](https://www.favro.com/). you can import your entire trello board easily, so nothing gets lost. then you will be able to make use of Favro's features, which include displaying a table. this is how you do it:

```
Fancy | Favro | Table
:- | :-: | -:
left | center | right
```

you separate each column with a vertical bar. then, in the second row, you need to specify how each column will be aligned. `:-` aligns to the left, `:-:` centres the text in the column, and `-:` aligns to the right.

see more info in the [documentation](https://help.favro.com/hc/en-us/articles/207178825-Markdown).